# Sharepoint 2010 How do i activate a Feature when a subsite is created

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a web template in visual studio that users can create sub sites from. I want to activate a feature when the subsite is created e.g. create list items etc.

How would i approach doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can associate a feature with a specific site template, but if you put "GLOBAL" instead of the template name, your feature will be activiated for [*all* websites created](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544294.aspx).

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="29D85C25-170C-4df9-A641-12DB0B9D4130" TemplateName="GLOBAL" />
</Elements>
```